# Scroll recyclerview to bottom when android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard

**Activity Layout.**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                     />

                <ImageView
                  />
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And the `ViewPager` contains a fragment whose layout is like below:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fl_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_done"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_done"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
         />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/some_other_layout" />
    <include layout="@layout/some_other_layout" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Problem is that button should be hidden when a `RecyclerView` item should be scrolled to the top of the keyboard as it has the button on the bottom of it's view to add new view dynamically.
I even tried putting `RecyclerView` under `NestedScrollView`, but nothing happens.

> Items in the `RecyclerView` is like this
>   ITEM
>   ITEM
>   ITEM
>   + Button
>
> DONE Button
>
> Done button is needed to be hidden behind the keyboard but rest of the view to be scrolled above the keyboard. For keeping done at it's place. I have used `adjustNothing` for the activity. But my problem is that `RecyclerView` items are also getting hidden behind the keyboard.

Comment: Kindly explain more and state the title clearly